# Cant execute a sh file via python script to linux server

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, paramiko

Hey I have following python code:

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    # Connect to the Linux server
    ssh.connect(hostname="name", username="root", password="password", port=22)
#if file exists it should be removed first
    ssh.exec_command("rm name")
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
#create file & add minecraft username to file
    f = sftp.open("name", "w")
    f.write(user)
    f.close()
#run bash file, which will whitelist user
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('./whitelist.sh')
    sftp.close()
    ssh.close()
```

This code is working on my home pc, but on my windows server the code dont execute "./whitelist.sh". I dont get a error message or something like that
What is the reason for that and how can i fix it?

Comment: You need to set the file to have execute permissions. BTW, there's no point to the `rm` first.

Comment: But why does it work if i execute this on my pc?

Comment: Are you trying to run a Bash/Sh script on a WIndows server? Is your WIndows server running WSL?

Comment: And there _is_ an error, you're just not checking exit status on the channel so you don't see it

Comment: yes thats with rm is stupid you are right

Comment: *But why does it work if i execute this on my pc?* Presumably it _does_ have execute permissions on your PC, but you're only sending the contents of the file and not copying its permissions.

Comment: Also, make sure you're not doing something silly like starting a background process attached to stdin, stdout and stderr channels that go away as soon as the client disconnects, causing the process to be killed even though it was successfully started. (There's a reason the right way to start and manage background processes is with systemd or another process supervisor!)

Comment: so do I have to change this execute permissions on my windows or linux server?

Comment: It's the new file you create on the remote end that isn't executable by default.

Comment: Also, have you thought about not creating a script at all and passing the code to execute as an argument to the shell, or as its stdin? No reason to fix file permissions when you could just stop using a file altogether.

Comment: I dont get it. In the file which i am creating whitelist.sh is read out the name. whitelist.sh isnt created by the script.

Comment: Sorry i am a little bit new

Comment: I tried, but that dont worked with screen. So i created a workaround

Comment: My fault, I misread what you were doing (on a phone here). That said, which thing are you saying "don't worked with screen"? How did you determine that it didn't work? What did it do instead of working? If you're using `screen` as a process supervisor... don't; that's systemd's job.

Comment: I determine it on that way.

The script is creating the name file (so i can see the file if i am typing ls in the linux console) but it dont run the command on my minecraft screen (i am running the server with screen). But if i execute whitelist.sh by console I see the command in screen, also when i execute the script on my pc.

Comment: Thanks. The message is "File does not exist". Maybe I have to write the complete path

Comment: but if i am running "ls", there is whitelist.sh in the dic

Comment: I get files does not exit because i wrote an echo with this... sorry forget this haha.  If i try this in console it works

Comment: Sorry to dont describe it clearly. I checked it some minutes ago and tried this code:

   ``` ssh.exec_command("rm name")
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    f = sftp.open("name", "w")
    f.write(user)
    f.close()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('./whitelist.sh')
    for line in stdout:
        print(line.strip())
    sftp.close()
    ssh.close() ```

and it works now.

Thanks for your help!